# UnicodeEncodeError with my code

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I have problem with UnicodeEncodeError in my users_information list:

```
{u'\u0633\u062a\u064a\u062f@nimbuzz.com': {'UserName': u'\u0633\u062a\u064a\u062f@nimbuzz.com', 'Code': 5, 'Notes': '', 'Active': 0, 'Date': '12/07/2014 14:16', 'Password': '560pL390T', 'Email': u'yuyb0y@gmail.com'}}
```

And I need to run this code to get users information:

```
def get_users_info(type, source, parameters):
    users_registertion_file = 'static/users_information.txt'
    fp = open(users_registertion_file, 'r')
    users_information = eval(fp.read())
    if parameters:
        jid = parameters+"@nimbuzz.com"
        if users_information.has_key(jid):
            reply(type, source, u"User name:\n" +str(users_information[jid]['UserName'])+ u"\nPassword:\n" +str(users_information[jid]['Password'])+ u"\nREG-code:\nP" +str(users_information[jid]['Code'])+ u"\nDate:\n" +str(users_information[jid]['Date'])+ u"\naccount status:\n " +str(users_information[jid]['Active']))
        else:
            reply(type, source, u"This user " +parameters+ u"  not in user list")
    else:
        reply(type, source, u"write the id after command")
```

but when I try to get users information I get this error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I try to unicode the `jid` using `unicode('utf8')`:

```
jid = parameters.encode('utf8')+"@nimbuzz.com"
```

but I get the same error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Please how I can solve this problem and as you see the UserName key in the users_information list look like:

```
u'\u0633\u062a\u064a\u062f@nimbuzz.com'
```

and the users_information list located in txt file.

Comment: Can you show at which line the error occurs? Post the complete traceback?

Comment: What does `repr(parameters)` look like? What is the *full* traceback of your error, is it exactly the same in all cases?

Comment: i get the error in line 8

Comment: quick hack : `from __future__ import unicode_literals` ??

Comment: @bluebelle: not a good idea unless you know what you are doing and need Python 3 compatibility. The OP doesn't know what they are doing here and `unicode_literals` won't fix the `str()` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You'll not find your user information unless `jid` is a unicode string. Make sure `parameters` is a unicode value here, and it'll be easier to use [string formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) here:

```
jid = u"{}@nimbuzz.com".format(parameters)
```

If you use an encoded bytestring, Python will **not** find your username in the dictionary as it won't know what encoding you used for the string and won't implicitly decode or encode to make the comparisons.

Next, you cannot call `str()` on a Unicode value without specifying a codec:

```
str(users_information[jid]['UserName'])
```

This is guaranteed to throw an `UnicodeEncodeError` exception if `users_information[jid]['UserName']` contains anything other than ASCII codepoints.

You need to use *Unicode* values throughout, leave encoding the value to the last possible moment (preferably by leaving it to a library).

You can use string formatting with `unicode` objects here too:

```
reply(type, source, 
      u"User name:\n{0[UserName]}\nPassword:\n{0[Password]}\n"
      u"REG-code:\nP{0[Code]}\nDate:\n{0[Date]}\n"
      u"account status:\n {0[Active]}".format(users_information[jid]))
```

This interpolates the various keys from `users_information[jid]` without calling `str` on each value.

Note that `dict.has_key()` has been deprecated; use the `in` operator to test for a key instead:

```
if jid in users_information:
```

Last but not least, don't use `eval()` if you can avoid it. You should use JSON here for the file format, but if you cannot influence that then at least use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) on the file contents instead of `eval()` and limit permissible input to *just* Python literal syntax:

```
import ast

# ...

users_information = ast.literal_eval(fp.read())
```

Comment: I try what you write and i get the answer in line 10. The user not in the list

Comment: @user3658169: exactly, because your keys are Unicode, but you are testing with just bytestrings.

Answer (score -1):

I had some problem years ago:

```
jid = parameters+"@nimbuzz.com"
```

must be

```
jid = parameters+u"@nimbuzz.com"
```

and put it at first or second row:

```
#coding:utf8
```

Example for Martijn Pieters - on my machine

```
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  1 2014, 17:30:21) 
[GCC 4.9.0 20140604 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=u'asdf'
>>> b='ваывап'
>>> a+b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> c=u'аыиьт'
>>> a+c
u'asdf\u0430\u044b\u0438\u044c\u0442'
>>>
```

Comment: No, concatenating Unicode with a ASCII bytestring is perfectly valid and won't lead to an encoding error. The PEP 263 comment **has no influence on implicit decoding or encoding**, please don't just Cargo Cult the use of such comments. The OP is **not** using non-ASCII source code here.

Comment: `>>> parameters = u'\u0633\u062a\u064a\u062f'`, then `>>> parameters+"@nimbuzz.com"` gives `u'\u0633\u062a\u064a\u062f@nimbuzz.com'`, for example.

Comment: But i cant understand how i can use ast.literal_eval() you mean i use like ast.literal_eval(fp.read()) ?

Comment: I get this error if i use `eval()` : SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positio
n 12-14: truncated \uXXXX escape

Comment: `NameError: global name 'ast' is not defined`

Comment: @user3658169: note that by continuing to comment on eri's post, you are pinging them with what are essentially questions directed at me. I don't get notified of those comments, I just happened to have this page open still. Better comment on my answer or use `@Martijn` to ping me if you respond to my comments here.

Comment: @Martijn i get the same error when i use `eval()` : `SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 12-14: truncated \uXXXX escape` and the list dosn't have any invalid data.

Comment: @user3658169: Glad to hear! Please do read my earlier comment on accepting an answer that was helpful to you. :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  1 2014, 17:30:21) 
[GCC 4.9.0 20140604 (prerelease)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=u'asdf'
>>> b='ваывап'
>>> a+b
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> c=u'аыиьт'
>>> a+c
u'asdf\u0430\u044b\u0438\u044c\u0442'
>>>

Comment: @eri: That's because the bytestring *contains non-ASCII codepoints*. I specifically used the term **ASCII bytestring** in my comment.

Comment: @eri: also note that the exception *differs*. You are getting a `UnicodeDecodeError`, **decoding**, the OP got a `UnicodeEncodeError`, **encoding**.